# gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain - Where are c++ std includes included?

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to switch from libc_nano to [picolibc](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc). I just compiled picolibc from source, and installed the libraries (`ninja` followed by `ninja install`). The latter command copied the lib and headers to certain locations in `/usr/local/picolibc/arm-none-eabi/*`

I also use `picolibc.specs` instead of `nano.specs` in my linker script.

When I now compile my project, it complains about conflicting declarations

```
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/include/sys/reent.h:292:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef struct __sFILE __FILE'
292 | typedef struct __sFILE   __FILE;
```

and

```
/usr/local/picolibc/arm-none-eabi/include/stdio.h:300:23: note: previous declaration as 'typedef struct __file __FILE'
  300 | typedef struct __file __FILE;
```

Obviously I no longer want to use the libraries and headers in `/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi`. But I have no idea why it resolves them. In my CMakeTextFile.txt I declare my own includes, but I never had to worry about where the C/C++ headers were located. It "just magically figured that out".

How does the compiler get the "std lib include path" from?

How can I instruct the compiler to look for standard libs elsewhere?

Comment: gcc and clang both have a "sysroot", which is where libraries and headers usually come from. If you don't explicitly specify, they try to automatically determine what the sysroot will be, which is a combination of common conventions, and flags used to build the compiler. Have you tried passing the `--sysroot=` flag during compilation? See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) for details.

Comment: @JonReeves that seems to prefix the `dir` so that the include path will find dir/usr/local. What would you suggest that I pass as directory then? `--sysroot=/usr/local/picolibc/arm-none-eabi`? That doesn't solve it anyway.

Comment: Yep, exactly, though of course I'd have to see the layout of that folder myself to be sure.

Comment: You have to give more details. `I no longer want to use the libraries and headers in /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi` How have you installed arm-none-eabi-gcc? What linux distribution are you using? `When I now compile my project` What source file are you compiling exactly that gives this error? What compiler version are you using? What compiler options, all of them, are you using? `I also use picolibc.specs` Please post the exact compiler option. Please post the content of `picolibc.specs`. `Where are c++ std includes included?` Are you using C or C++? Gcc or G++?

Comment: `error: conflicting declaration` Are there no other compiler messages? Is there no "In included file: here.h: from here.h: from here.h:"? Please post all verbatim compiler messages. `In my CMakeTextFile.txt` Please create an [MCVE], please post your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Found the problem. arm-none-eabi c++ stdlib expects only one std lib to be installed. I have two. Replacing `#include_next` with `#include` in the std c++ headers solved the problem. I can imagine this is a bit too specific for stackoverflow. Delete the question if that's the case